# Is there a way to get the blank accdb files generated by Right-Click "New" dropdown's "New Microsoft Access Database", to work?

Tags: windows-10, ms-access-2010

New accdb files generated by the right-click "New" dropdown, are 0 bytes, don't work with MS Access 2010, and lead to "Unrecognized Database Format" when I try to open them on one of my Windows 10 computers.

But it's fine on another one, I think...

Is there a way to get the blank accdb files generated by Right-Click "New" dropdown's "New Microsoft Access Database", to not fail immediately?

Like how if I did the same thing, but with a MS Word 2010 Document instead of a MS Access 2010 Database, executing it would lead to a nice empty document.

Comment: On my computer, this generates a 488 KB file, which is a copy of "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\1031\ACCESS12.ACC". Check there (your path will be different).

Comment: @Andre - Yeah, I don't got that. ... Make that an answer? I guess I need to put a blank databases there under that name...

Comment: Why was this moved? IIRC, this was on Superuser?

Answer (score 1):

The Explorer context menu "New Microsoft Access Database" tries to copy a template file from a subfolder of the Office installation to the current folder.

The template file for .accdb is `ACCESS12.ACC`, and is located e.g. here for a German Office 2010 installation:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\1031\ACCESS12.ACC
```

For a `en-us` installation, the [language code](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/languagecodes.php) and subfolder is `1033`.

If the file is missing, create an empty database in the appropriate location - you can set your favorite database options beforehand, so you don't have to do that over and over again.

See also [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/database-file-creation-via-command-line/405c1a96-201f-48f2-82c8-32c7f182ab3a?auth=1).